# How to pass HashMap from JSF bean via hidden input field to JS function

Tags: javascript, jsf, hashmap, hidden-field

I have the below JSF form.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText value="#{duedimgr.regulatoryList}" onblur="checkmember(this)" />
    <h:inputHidden id="hiddenField" value="#{duedimgr.regulatoryItem}" />
</h:form>
```

The `regularotyItem` is a `HashMap`. How can I get it in the JS function?

```
checkmember(newmemberobj) {
    var oldmemobj = document.getElementById("myForm:hiddenField").value;
}
```

Comment: Having problems formatting your question? Please read this reference page for help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: An html input cannot contain a java hashmap. It can contain a string. And since you can encode a hashmap into a json string. Try that.

Comment: How to convert hasmap to json string and get all the hashmap value in json string?

Comment: Just make Google your friend, or even just the stackoverflow searchengine… Please… we cannot and should not have to do all this basic work for you. I'mnot even going to mark it as a duplicate of one such answer, since I still would have done the work (but a post about this exists in stackoverflow, I just checked)